# How do i save a canvas on p5js web editor after drawing on it?

Tags: javascript, save, processing

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xCbP.png)

The save function only saves the board as it starts, how do I save the canvas after drawing on it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your sketch.  On my system it places the image in the Downloads folder.

```
function keyTyped() {
  if (key == 's') {
    saveCanvas('photo', 'png');
  }
}
```